# What is the difference between wscompile and wsimport?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

What is the difference between wscompile and wsimport. Can you please let me know when to wscompile.
I normally use wsimport to get all ws artifacts from wsdl. I am confused when to use wscompile?

Comment: JAX-RPC's tool is wscompile , JAX-WS' tool is wsimport

Comment: Is it not wsdl2java in JAX-RPC??

Answer (score 0):

As per my information,
JAX-WS has simplified the development of Web Service clients when compared to JAX-RPC. 
Both technologies have a tool for importing a WSDL to generate client side artifacts. 
JAX-RPC's tool is wscompile, JAX-WS' tool is wsimport.

The advantage of JAX-WS clients over JAX-RPC clients is portability. 
JAX-WS generates portable artifacts at much higher percentage, while JAX-RPC generated artifacts are not all portable.

Answer (score 0):

The tool wsimport works on a WSDL file which is an XML document describing the web service.
The tool wsimport does not care to the style of the service (RPC/DOCUMENT) as described in the WSDL.
If the WSDL has RPC-style, it will generate the client stubs for consuming RPC-style web services and similarly for document-style.