# Consume WSDL using SOAP client using dynamic proxy

Tags: web-services, soap

I m trying to consume my web service using dynamic proxy where i get my interfaces at compile time and Services get fetched at the run time.

Documentation provides me wscompile command to generate the endpoint interfaces but this command don't exist in my system.

Need Help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well regarding:

*Documentation provides me wscompile command to generate the endpoint interfaces but this command don't exist in my system.*

Instead of wscompile, you could also use wsimport which is included in the Java JDK.

(if you ask about the difference: [What is the difference between wscompile and wsimport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167338/what-is-the-difference-between-wscompile-and-wsimport))

Comment: But i want to create interface only as a stub and wsimport will bring all static stubs.Should i delete all other stubs and then use it as dynamic proxy?